# cat program in Prolog

Tags: io, prolog

In order to learn Prolog, I have implemented the `cat` command in Prolog. I want to know if the code is idiomatic and what could be improved.

File `args.pl`:

```
:- module(args, [withFilesOrUserInput/2]).

withFilesOrUserInput(StreamFunction, []) :-
    call(StreamFunction, user_input).

withFilesOrUserInput(StreamFunction, [Filename]) :-
    withFile(StreamFunction, Filename).

withFilesOrUserInput(StreamFunction, [Head|Tail]) :-
    withFile(StreamFunction, Head),
    withFilesOrUserInput(StreamFunction, Tail).

withFile(StreamFunction, Filename) :-
    open(Filename, read, StreamIn),
    call(StreamFunction, StreamIn),
    close(StreamIn).
```

File `cat.pl`:

```
:- use_module(args).

main(Argv) :-
    prompt(_, ''),
    withFilesOrUserInput(catStream, Argv).

catStream(Stream) :-
    copy_stream_data(Stream, user_output),
    flush_output(user_output).
```

Note: I'm using SWI-Prolog.

Answer (score 5):

+1, good question.

The Prolog convention is to use *underscores* for readability. Why? `because_it_is_easy_to_read_even_long_names_with_underscores`, `butItIsExtremelyHardToReadEvenShorterNamesWithMixedCaps`!

A good naming convention is to use one noun per argument, declaratively describing what the argument stands for.

In SWI-Prolog, check out `library(pio)`: The pure way to do what you want is to use a DCG to describe a list, and then to use `phrase_from_file/2` to apply the DCG to a file.

The advantage is clear: You can then readily test your predicates on the toplevel alone, without even requiring a file, just by stating the input as a regular Prolog term.

This helps a lot also when writing test cases.

**EDIT**: I give you one example how DCGs can help you here. It is not yet completely pure, because this DCG contains output itself. However, it is much simpler than your code, and you can test this predicate without even needing a file, and then transparently apply *the same* code to a file too:

```
:- use_module(library(pio)).
:- set_prolog_flag(double_quotes, codes).

cat --> [].
cat --> [C], { put_char(C) }, cat.
```

This DCG describes a list of character codes, and outputs each code.

Sample use:

```
?- phrase(cat, "test").
test
true.
```

Now, with `phrase_from_file/2` from Ulrich Neumerkel's `library(pio)`, we can transparently apply the same DCG to a file too:

```
?- once(phrase_from_file(cat, 'cat.pl')).
```

With output:

```
:- use_module(library(pio)).
:- set_prolog_flag(double_quotes, codes).

cat --> [].
cat --> [C], { put_char(C) }, cat.
```

i.e., the same program as above, which I had saved it `cat.pl`.

I am using `once/1` to commit to the first solution found (there is no further solution, but a choice-point left).

Comment: According to the [SWI-Prolog manual](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=pio) `library(pio)` doesn't support pipes. Can the situation handled by `withFilesOrUserInput(StreamFunction, [])` still be covered by `phrase_from_file/2` resp. `phrase_from_stream/2`?

Comment: Also, I don't see how a DCG helps here. I'm not looking at what I read, I'm just forwarding it to `stdout`.

Comment: I have included a DCG that I hope you find useful to express this more declaratively and compactly.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not proficient enough in Prolog to figure out how this would help. I can get this working with files, but I cannot get this working with `stdin`. Also, when I use your solution and the file contains binary data, I get `ERROR: Unknown message: goal_failed(main([binaryFile]))`.

Comment: Also, what if the file in question is very huge, like 20 GB?

Comment: You can set encoding options with `phrase_from_file/3`, for example, using `[encoding(octet)]` as options.

Comment: If you try it, you will see that files of 20 GB and also much larger work very well too with this approach. The reason is that `library(pio)` reads the file lazily, and only stores a small buffer in memory, which is automatically reclaimed when it is no longer needed for processing. To apply this to streams, use `phrase_from_stream/2`, also available via `library(pio)`. To fully understand this idiomatic Prolog solution, I recommend you read a good primer on DCGs.

Comment: Using `phrase_from_file/3` with `[encoding(octet)]` solved it. Thanks for that. About performance: For a ~750 MB file, the original `cat` command needed 12s, the Prolog program with `copy_stream_data` needed 31s, the Prolog program with DCG and `phrase_from_file` needed 9m 3s. Is `phrase_from_file/3` with DCG slow in general, or am I doing something wrong? Here's the code: http://pastebin.com/02aAjMBT

Comment: You can specify a buffer size with `[buffer_size(Number)]`, this may improve performance somewhat. Other than that, I recommend to raise performance bottlenecks that are important for your use case on the SWI mailing list or as an issue on github: It may be possible to improve the library to get better performance for large binary files. Regarding your code on pastebin: You do not need to special-case `main/1` for a single-element list (second clause): This case is subsumed by the other two clauses.

Comment: I think the special case `main/1` is needed once `main/0` starts using `phrase_from_stream`. `main/1` is not allowed to call `main/0` to terminate.